# PHPUnit ensuring a trait satisfies an interface

Tags: php, testing, interface, phpunit, traits

Let's look at the code in [`psr/log`](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/master/Psr/Log/), in particular:

- [`LoggerAwareTrait`](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/master/Psr/Log/LoggerAwareTrait.php)
- [`LoggerAwareInterface`](https://github.com/php-fig/log/blob/master/Psr/Log/LoggerAwareInterface.php)

As you know, a trait cannot implement an interface, so these two parts need a class to be successfully connected together.

Let's say I cover testing of the trait (it's relatively easy via PHPUnit's `getMockForTrait`). The next thing to test is that I want to *prove that the trait satisfies the interface*.

In terms of code, it looks simple enough:

```
public function testThatTraitSatisfiesInterface()
{
    $className = 'test_class_' . uniqid();
    $classCode = sprintf(
        'class %s implements %s { use %s; }',
        $className,
        LoggerAwareInterface::class,
        LoggerAwareTrait::class
    );

    eval($classCode); // ewww :see_no_evil:
    new $className(); // no errors? good, test successful
}
```

A have a few concerns here:

- I'd like to avoid `eval()` as much as possible (even if I know that it's what drives PHPUnit anyway), but..
- I'd rather use PHPUnit's functionality if at all possible

So the big question is, are there any alternatives?

Comment: Why do you care? It's more important that a class implements an interface, than how it does so.

Comment: The focus here is not the class, but the trait. Indeed, I don't care about the class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just creating the class as a test asset:

```
namespace Foo\Bar\Test\Asset;

use Psr\Log;

final class LoggerAware implements Log\LoggerAwareInterface
{
    use Log\LoggerAwareTrait;
}
```

And then asserting it implements the interface:

```
namespace Foo\Bar\Test;

use PhpUnit\Framework;
use Psr\Log;

final class LoggerAwareTest extends Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testImplementsLoggerAwareInterface()
    {
        $loggerAware = new Asset\LoggerAware();

        $this->assertInstanceOf(Log\LoggerAwareInterface::class, $loggerAware);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a possibility.

Comment: Good answer and suggestion with creating the mock object verbatim. The assertion is not needed IMHO. PHP will give a fatal-error on object creation if the interface would not be (fully) satisfied, see  https://3v4l.org/gAlRI - Can't say from top of my head if PHPUnit catches this (Error catchable) or exits with 255 exit code (preventing further tests) - I guess this depends on PHP version used. The assertion won't be called in any case. So the test is more of a safety check (and perhaps not even necessary at all, but that is subjective as I can't speak for the OP).

Comment: @hakre The assertion is useful insofar as it makes it explicit what we care about. Also useful if we configure to be strict about tests that do not assert anything (see https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/risky-tests.html).